# AttributeError in getText method

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, gettext

When i scraping, everthing goes well, but sometime when i scrap many informations
i get

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'h1'**.
Below is my code:

```
    for index, link in enumerate(all_links):
        self.driver.execute_script("window.open('" + link + "');")
        print(link)
        sleep(9)
        self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[1])
        final_soup = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        image = final_soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'someClass_1'})
        filename = 'image_' + str(index) + '.png'
        title = final_soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'someClass_2'})
        sleep(1)
        origin_title = title.h1.getText()   # here is the problem
        print(origin_title)
```

This error comes sometimes, the weird thing is that i check the html for the specific link and all looks the same as the others links, i don't know why i get the error.The text in h1 tag is there.

I try to increase sleep, but nothing changed.The other thing, that i can do is to add try - catch:

```
 try:
    origin_title = title.h1.getText()   # here is the problem
    print(origin_title)
 except AttributeError:
    pass
```

But my problem here is that, i don't want to pass if doesn't find the text in h1 tag, The text is there and i should get it in some way

Comment: Did you check the encoding?

Comment: # coding=utf8, i have this in the head of my script

Comment: Can you give the link you are trying to scrape for better assistance?

Answer (score 0):

please correct your code line with this line

```
final_soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'someClass_2)
```

with this line

```
final_soup.find('div', {'class': 'someClass_2'})
```

you missed the " '} "

Comment: Sorry, that was a typeError.  Problem still remains, is not there the issue

Comment: full code needs chromedriver to work, you can check only the code below final_soup = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source, 'lxml').
Also import: # coding=utf8,
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Comment: what I can understand from your code is that your code is not able to get any 'div' tag with the given attributes, So its returning None.

Comment: you missed two characters  ' and } in the find function. please check whether you write properly or it still has a typo ?

Comment: Sure, maybe the div tag or the div.h1 tag, but searching the link for the specific item, it has both tags.Have in mind that, this happend only some times when my script runs.

Comment: its not about h1 tag, you can't find h1 in Nonetype, thats why it is thowing error
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'h1'

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it's not there the problem. I get AttributeError

Comment: print this line and check the result,

    title = final_soup.find('div', {'class': 'someClass_2'})

Comment: I check it again the category which have the specific item and it runs smoothly, without error. So the problem comes only if i scrape many data it the midle of running.

Answer (score 0):

This code makes the work, which i need. It looks that the error maybe comes from unexpecting internet disconnecting or no server response.

```
 while True:
            try:
                title = final_soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'someclass'})
                sleep(1)
                origin_title = title.h1.getText()
                print(origin_title)
            except Exception as ex:
                print('number of try', i)
                sleep(1)
                i += 1
                continue
            break
```